# Python combination of n dimensional array elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of arrays as below

```
list1 = [['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06'], ['01', '64', '2f'], ['00', '1f', '17']]
```

I need all the possible combination of these elements like

```
010100, 01011f, 010117, 010200, 01021f, etc.
```

Comment: [What site to use if you have a "gimme teh codez" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108551/what-site-to-use-if-you-have-a-gimme-teh-codez-question)

Comment: what have you tried? This is not a Do my homework for me site we will help you fix what is wrong with your code, but you need to do some work so you can learn. Hint: You need to write 3 nested loops that pick one element from each sub list.

Comment: i tried the meshgrid library, but it does not allows me to specify list

Comment: import numpy as np
list1 = [['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06'], ['01', '64', '2f'], ['00', '1f', '17']]

comb_array = np.array(np.meshgrid(
    list1)).T.reshape(-1, len(list1)
  
print("\nCombine array:")
print(comb_array)

Comment: Please don't post code in comments! Instead, [edit] your question and update it with all relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and get what you want:

```
import itertools

list1 = [['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06'], ['01', '64', '2f'], ['00', '1f', '17']]

for prd in itertools.product(*list1):
    print(''.join(prd))
```

Output:

```
010100
01011f
010117
016400
01641f
016417
012f00
...
062f00
062f1f
062f17
```